# How to use ffdshow with WPF-Mediakit

Tags: c#, wpf, dxva, ffdshow, wpf-mediakit

By default LAV Decoder, but I'd like to use ffdshow with hardware acceleration for decoding. 
I saw these lines in the file *ClassId.cs*

```
public static readonly Guid FFDShowVideo = new Guid("04FE9017-F873-410e-871E-AB91661A4EF7");
public static readonly Guid FFDShowVideoRaw = new Guid("0B390488-D80F-4a68-8408-48DC199F0E97");
public static readonly Guid FFDShowVideoDXVA = new Guid("0B0EFF97-C750-462c-9488-B10E7D87F1A6");
```

The used decoders are defined in *MediaUriPlayer*

```
public MediaUriPlayer()
{
    Splitter = "LAV Splitter";
    SplitterSource = "LAV Splitter Source";
    VideoDecoder = "LAV Video Decoder";
    AudioDecoder = "LAV Audio Decoder";
}
```

So the question is, how do I enable FFDShowVideoDXVA? What's the correct name for the decoder or am I totally on wrong path here?

And if I manage to enable FFDShowVideoDXVA, is the hardware acceleration enabled by default (if not, how do I programmatically enable it?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

LAV filters have HW acceleration, too, see `https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/wiki/Usage`. However, it has to be set manually. There's already an [GitHub issue #31](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/issues/31) to set the acceleration automatically.

If you want to enforce ffdshow can set `MediaUriPlayer.VideoDecoder, Splitter` properties. (Those GUIDs are not used in the code.) I do not know ffdshow in details, but IMO it's similar: you have to set DXVA manually.